# Has LEGO Made A Minifigure-Scale Shopping Cart Piece?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

For the current MOC I am working on, I am going to need a LEGO Minifigure-scale shopping cart. I thought I had seen one in an official set, but after searching [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page) extensively, I am now not sure they have. **Has LEGO produced a shopping cart piece or will I just have to make my own?**

Comment: There is one Friends scale shopping cart. But that is probably not helpful I guess.

Comment: @Aziraphale why not?

Comment: @Aziraphale On the contrary, that is actually quite helpful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [41118 Heartlake Supermarket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41118-1&name=Heartlake%20Supermarket&category=%5BFriends%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) contains a Friends scale shopping cart. This is how it looks like:
[image]

There is, however, a cute little MOC design with [Window 1 x 2 x 2 2/3 Pane Lattice Diamond with Rounded Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30046#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) on both sides and 1x2 tile modified grilles. This is, I think, a perfect shopping cart:

[image]

@MindS1 This is how far I got with it. The panes bend the grilles quite a bit. I would consider this an illegal building technique. I also don't see how the droid arms connect to the wheels and to the basket part.
[image]

Comment: The Friends shopping cart is most likely the one I've seen before. That design is perfect! I guess I'm finally going to be able to put my Lattice Windows to good use! :D

Comment: That is a really excellent design. It's so hard to find good solutions at that scale!  
What is the minifigure holding onto in that picture? And how is it attached to the grille?

Comment: The grills are the other way around on the MOC...

Answer (score 5):

*LEGO* heard the wishes, and finally put one out new this year *(2019)*.

[image]

[image]
[image]

*[Part #49649 Minifigure, Utensil Shopping Cart Frame.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=49649&idColor=36#T=C&C=36)*

*[Part #2496 Wheel Skateboard / Trolley.](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=41362-1)*

Is this for a *[Fortnite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hS4p8ziZ7gQ)* project?
[image]